# Azure DevOps AzureCLI task with scriptPath option failed to authenticate to create Azure Container Instance

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

We are using YAML pipelines in Azure DevOps.

One of the tasks in the pipeline is `AzureCLI` that creates `ACI container`.
The image we build and push in the previous steps of the pipeline.

When we run this task from external script it fails with the message:
`The image '***.azurecr.io/image:1.0' in container group '***' is not accessible. 
Please check the image and registry credential.`

When we change script type to `inlineScript` it works correctly.

Following is the form that doesn't work(`scriptPath`).

```yaml
- task: AzureCLI@1
  displayName: 'Run tests'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION)
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'scriptPath'
    scriptPath: 'run_tests.sh'
```

Here is the form that works(`inlineScript`)

```yaml
- task: AzureCLI@1
    displayName: 'Run tests'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: '$(AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION)'
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: 'az container create -g *** --registry-login-server ***.azurecr.io --registry-username *** --registry-password *** --image image -n test --cpu 1 --memory 8 --restart-policy Never --command-line "dotnet test.dll -n testApp -c 1000"'
```

The script will be longer than one line.
Any clue how to create azure container instances from external script file (`scriptLocation: 'scriptPath'`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created container instance in both ways (`script` and `inline`). Here is my configuration:

build definition:

```yaml
steps:
- task: replacetokens@3
  inputs:
    targetFiles: 'stackoverflow/12-container-instance/create-container-instance.sh'
    encoding: 'auto'
    writeBOM: true
    actionOnMissing: 'warn'
    keepToken: false
    tokenPrefix: '#{'
    tokenSuffix: '}#'
    useLegacyPattern: false
    enableTelemetry: true
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Run tests 1'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(AzureSubscription)'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'scriptPath'
    scriptPath: 'stackoverflow/12-container-instance/create-container-instance.sh'

- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Run tests 2'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(AzureSubscription)'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: 'az container create -g TheCodeManual --name myapp2 --image $(Image) --registry-password $(RegistryPassword) --registry-user $(RegistryUser)'
```

and `create-container-instance.sh` file

```sh
az container create -g TheCodeManual --name myapp1 --image #{Image}# --registry-password #{RegistryPassword}# --registry-user #{RegistryUser}#
```

I used token replace task to do not expose sensitive data in source control.

However, both ways work for me.

What I noticed I don't use `--registry-login-server ***.azurecr.io` but instead of this I provide full path to image like here:

```
az container create -g MyResourceGroup --name myapp --image myAcrRegistry.azurecr.io/myimage:latest --registry-password password --registry-user userName
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Thanks to that I spot that we got issue with quotation marks around the password.